# Entity Framework generation generates nothing

Tags: asp.net, sql, model, ado.net, entity

I created a database (called Data1) in sql server 2008 using sa account, and then a table (called Table1) in Data1. However, after i have used the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to generate entity from Data1, no entity is generated.

But i can generate entities for the system tables from the master database.

Would anyone give me some advice for this?
Thx a lot

Comment: You need to provide more information. Did you give same result on another newly created table? Try it. Give us the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: HI, I Have tried serveral times and found that all tables created by me cannot be generated to entity, even though those table created by me in master database. 

Those system tables in the database, and those database (.mdf file) that i found in the source code of some books can be generated to entity.